# jQuery fadeIn / fadeOut

Tags: jquery, html

Essentially I'm trying to fade div 1 in then out after a specified amount of time. After div 1 has faded out, shortly after div 2 will fade in.

https://jsfiddle.net/hwyw5ssf/5/

```
$("#title").hide(function(){
  $("#title").fadeIn(5000).next().delay('500', function(){
    $("#title").fadeOut(5000);
    $("#hub").hide(function(){
      $("#hub").fadeIn(5000);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend selecting the divs differently than I did, .next() is a useful function in this regard and could in this example be used to replace the explicit reference to '#hub' for instance.

```
// hide all divs
$( 'div' ).hide()

// fade in: duration 1s on complete call function
$( '#title' ).fadeIn(1000, function(){

    // fade out: duration 1s, on complete call function
    $( '#title' ).fadeOut(1000, function(){

    // fade in: duration 1s
    $( '#hub' ).fadeIn(1000)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/hwyw5ssf/6/

```js
$('div').hide();
$('#title').fadeIn("slow", function(){
  $(this).fadeOut("slow", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#hub').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 2000);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title">Help please.</div>
<div id="hub">not sure what to do</div>
```

First div will `fadeOut` immediately & second div will `fadeout` after `2sec` of first div.

And for 2sec gap I've used `setTimeout`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That simply just fades both divs out, I'm trying to fadeIn div 1 then fade it Out. After div 1 fades out after a short amount of time, div 2 fades in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this, just use setTimeout function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
         $("#title").fadeIn(2000)
         $("#hub").fadeIn(4000)
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function(){
         $("#title").fadeOut(4000)
         $("#hub").fadeOut(2000)
        }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#hub, #title{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title">Help please.</div>
<div id="hub">not sure what to do</div>
```